Twitch message filter from spammers
I'm moderating twitch chat using bot on node.js.
We have a problem, sometimes bots are raiding our channel and spam messages like:

88|неodeтыe голышкuнсы в т_еле_ж̴eч_кe dosia739
гolышkи шkoднuчku в-телеграмчике : juice644 |82
87|rолышкu wkоlьницы в теlеграм4икe / recrenт361
89|спуctuл cпeрму на tрусы шкодниц - тeлеrрам aunkerе450
62 oтсосала охрaнниkу, чтобы tот пустил 6ез смeнки, чеkай синегрaм : buster824
88 пaрни 13 leт дрочаt dруг дpугу при пoдруге в тгшноu recrеnt361
84 clиb wkolьниц в телеrе -> juice644
JN шkодницы 6aлyются b тyалете wколы в t.елеге strоgo376
124_rолышku шкоdничkи в-теlегрaмчиkе : recrent361
Le педомамки е6ут новорoждённых маль4uкоb, смotри те-л-еrу > aunkere450
87|cлuв нeодетыx wkoдниц b..телеге olyаshaa123
87|отсосала оxpаннику, чтобы тот nустил без сменки, 4еkай сuнeграm / recrеnt361
rolые wкоlьницы в_teлеrраме recrеnt361 Ap
rоленькue голышkи b-tелeграмчиwе recrеnt361 |38
wd ра3dетые гоlышkи b teлегe muмino531
Dw cлиb шкoльнuц b telеге -> strogo376
123_лютая заnpеwенка со шкodницamи , те-лeграмчик miradota328
124_cлив нeодетых шkоlодpыг в t.е.лeгe juicе644
rоlышки wkолодрыги b тeлeграмчиkе juicе584 YW
гоlенькиe wkoднuчки в телегpаmище - аunkere450 |48
голeнькие шkоднu4kи b телеграmищe juicе644 |6
18 rоlыe шkodницы b телегe дosia739
hJ гolые шkоlьницы в_tеlегpамe mixazvеr451
123_неодеtыe wкodницы в-tе-леграmчuке olyashaа123
Tl гoленькиe гoлыwки_в_tеleгpаме - sтeel537
15 rоlышки шкоdнuчkи в-телеrрамчukе general301
11 rолышkи шкоlодрыru в teлеграмчuке strоgo376
oK clив шkoльниц b тeleграме мumino531
93 lюtая̾ заnpещенка со шкодницами , те-лerрамчuк juicе584
124_oдноkлaсснuк e6ет 15 lетнюю в те_ле_rе > rosтislav441
Jv наказала сына и засtавиlа ли3aть пя̾ткu в этоm т.r. tx740

And I have lack of understanding what is similar and how to differ sthis messages from normal chat users
The way I do it right now is adding every last letter and numbers to check if it contains in message, but I dont think it's reliable for future and works only after spam is occur
if (
    text.toLowerCase().includes('a739') ||
    text.toLowerCase().includes("e644") ||
    text.toLowerCase().includes("e450")
    //etc.
  ) {
    await apiClient.asUser(
      nyaka,
      async (ctx) =>
        await ctx.moderation.banUser(msg.channelId, {
          reason: `${user}: ${text}`,
          user: msg.userInfo.userId,
        })
    );


Just check for numeric characters at the beginning and end of each line.

@RobertHarvey The problem is - it would hurt every user. Like message: "He is playing bad. It's surely 322"

Depends how crazy you want to go, but on the upper end https://developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflowjs-comment-spam-detection

That's why I said at the beginning and end of each line.

@James I'll look into that, but I think it's way to advance for me

@RobertHarvey In that case it won't detect half of spam messages

But it will detect the other half.  No spam system is perfect.  If you want a better one, look into the many, very good Bayesian systems that are out there to detect spam.

@RobertHarvey I guess, you right. Half of them is still good, but if there are some better ways to filter it - that would be great
